# Make last menu item background different color that extends and fills the rest of the space?

Tags: html, css

The menu background is full screen, but the menu itself is fixed width. Last menu item is different color.

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li class="last"><a href="#">Last Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #183650;
}
.nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width: 500px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.nav ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: block;
}
.nav ul li.last a {
  background-color: #20bef2;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lnpysxze/14/

And it looks like this:
[image]

But the light blue color needs to fill the rest of the space to the right, which is beyond fixed-width menu and look like this:
[image]

The button stays same width, the new space filled with the light blue should not extend as part of the button.

Comment: bit hacky but I would use an after on the last li: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnpysxze/20/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using a pseudo element added to the last list item:

```
.nav ul li.last {
  position: relative;
}

.nav ul li.last::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #20bef2;
}
```

Here's a full working example (with `overflow: hidden;` added to the nav menu because the pseudo element is going to overflow - no way of determining remaining width):

```css
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #183650;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width: 500px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.nav ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: block;
}
.nav ul li.last a {
  background-color: #20bef2;
}

.nav ul li.last {
  position: relative;
}

.nav ul li.last::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #20bef2;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li class="last"><a href="#">Last Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but what does `width: 1000px;` do exactly? What if screen exceeds that?

Comment: That's just a large value to make sure it covers the area. There's no way of calculating this width, so I just set it to 1000px. It could easily be changed to 3000px, 4000px or anything though. The overflow will stop it at the edge of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this isn't possible if there's `max-width: 500px` on the *parent* `ul`. Without it, you can just give `flex: 1` to the `.first` and `li:last-child` elements and adjust their `text-align`ments and `margin`s. Do note that doing it with the *pseudo-element* is just like adding an additional *element*, though I don't know if your intentions are *functional* or pure *visual*:

```css
body {margin: 0}

.nav {
  background-color: #183650;
}

.nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /*max-width: 500px;*/
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav ul li:first-child {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.nav ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: block;
}

.last {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #20bef2;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#">Last Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```